# aframe - How to get what element collided with another element

Tags: aframe, webvr

I'm developing a simple VR game using A-Frame, and I'm struggling with collisions.
Specifically, I'm using aframe-physics-extras.min.js for the collision-filter, and aframe-extras.min.js for "hit" (and "hitend", in case) event handling.
In my game there are many bullets and many targets. I can get a "hit" event when a target is hit, but I can't find a way to get what bullet hit that target.
When a target is hit and I use the "hit" event, I can then refer to that specific target using "this.el", so that for example I can remove it from the scene with this.el.sceneEl.removeChild(this.el).
Is there a way to get the element that collided with the target? For example something like this.el.collidingEntity ?

This is the relevant part of the code:

```
// collision-filter : Requires aframe-physics-extras
// hit (and hitend, if used) : Requires aframe-extras

AFRAME.registerComponent('hit_target', {
init: function() {
this.el.addEventListener('hit', (e) => {

this.el.sceneEl.removeChild(this.el); // This is the Target

// this.el.collidingEntity.sceneEl.removeChild(this.el.collidingEntity); // THIS is what I'd need, to know what hit the Target

})
}
});


// Bullet
var elbullet = document.createElement('a-sphere');
elbullet.setAttribute('class', 'bullet');
elbullet.setAttribute('scale', '0.05 0.05 0.05');
elbullet.setAttribute('opacity', '1');
elbullet.setAttribute('color', '#ff3333');
elbullet.setAttribute('position', point);
elbullet.setAttribute('collision-filter', 'group: bullet; collidesWith: target');
elbullet.setAttribute('dynamic-body', 'shape: sphere; sphereRadius:0.05;');
elbullet.setAttribute('sphere-collider','');
document.querySelector('a-scene').appendChild(elbullet);

// Target
var eltarget = document.createElement('a-gltf-model');
eltarget.setAttribute('src', '#target');
eltarget.setAttribute('class', 'target');
eltarget.setAttribute('scale', '1 1 1');
eltarget.setAttribute('opacity', '1');
eltarget.setAttribute('position', (rnd(-8,8,0))+' '+(rnd(-8,8,0))+' '+(rnd(-20,-6,0)));
eltarget.setAttribute('collision-filter', 'group: target; collidesWith: bullet');
eltarget.setAttribute('hit_target','');
document.querySelector('a-scene').appendChild(eltarget);
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

A-Frame's [aabb-collider](https://github.com/supermedium/superframe/tree/master/components/aabb-collider) component can help you print out the following:

- bullet collided with ["plate_big", "plate_small"]

When the bullet hits the target, `hitstart` event will fire.

- You can use `event.target.id` to get the bullet id.
- You can use `event.target.components["aabb-collider"]["intersectedEls"]` to get the targets.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  document.querySelectorAll("a-entity").forEach(function(entity) {
    entity.addEventListener("hitstart", function(event) {
      console.log(
        event.target.id,
        "collided with",
        event.target.components["aabb-collider"]["intersectedEls"].map(x => x.id)
      );
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.0.4/aframe.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/aframe-aabb-collider-component@3.2.0/dist/aframe-aabb-collider-component.min.js"></script>

<a-scene>
  <a-entity id="bullet" geometry="primitive: cone; radiusBottom:0.5; height:2;" material="color: red" position="0 1 -5" aabb-collider="objects: a-entity"></a-entity>
  <a-entity id="plate_big" geometry="primitive: cylinder; height:0.2;" material="color: blue" position="0 0.8 -5" aabb-collider="objects: a-entity"></a-entity>
  <a-entity id="plate_small" geometry="primitive: cylinder; height:0.2; radius:0.6;" material="color: blue" position="0 1.4 -5" aabb-collider="objects: a-entity"></a-entity>
</a-scene>
```

Comment: Hi I just tried this solution, and my event.target.components doesn't have a property 'aabb-collider'

```
Uncaught TypeError: hitevent.target.components['aabb-collider'] is undefined
```